# Limit custom price per kilo to 2 decimals in WooCommerce + ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, price

The following code allows to show the price per kilo using WooCommerce and ACF by creating a `price_per_kilo` custom product field via ACF:

```
global $product;

$price = $product->get_price();

$weight = $product->get_weight();

$id = $product->get_id();

$value = 1000 * $price / $weight;

update_field('price_per_kilo', $value, $id); // this code updates data for this field

the_field('price_per_kilo', $product->$id ); //show price per kilo
```

However it shows a lot of digits when the result is not round, do you know how I can limit to two decimal places ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First here is a mistake in `the_field('price_per_kilo', $product->$id );` where `$product->$id` should replaced by `$id` or `$product->get_id()`.

You can use `number_format()` to limit the price to 2 decimals, so in your code just replace:

```
$value = 1000 * $price / $weight;
```

with:

```
$value = number_format( 1000 * $price / $weight, 2 );
```

Or to display **a formatted price in WooCommerce with the currency**, use `wc_price()` formatting price function as follows, replacing:

```
the_field('price_per_kilo', $product->$id );
```

with:

```
echo wc_price( get_field('price_per_kilo', $product->get_id() ) );
```